# Timetable in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using this package in flutter web, https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_timetable/latest/ . Somebody knows how to scroll horizontally with the mouse or even with the arrows on the keyboard?

I searched tried some things but nothing worked.
I would appreciate all the ideas you can bring to me.
Thanks.

Comment: is this for desktop ,web or both?

Comment: this is for both